# Why was my answer deleted due to a minor error?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, vote-to-undelete

I wrote this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73505555/9026710) with a solution to my own question. But after a while it was deleted by a moderator. The reason was that there was a mistake in my answer which could've been easily corrected.

[image]

Answer (score 18):

> The reason was that there was a mistake in my answer which could've been easily corrected.

No, that was not the reason the answer was deleted. The answer was deleted because someone [flagged it as "not an answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer), and the moderator who handled the flag agreed that what you had posted did not meet [our standards for an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Possibly, the moderator read this phrase at the bottom of your answer:

> But, I still have no idea why it was happening.

and thought that you were not providing a solution to the problem, only adding additional information (which should be added by editing the question, not by posting an answer) or perhaps attempting to ask a clarification question.

I would consider undeleting the answer (since I'm not sure that the "not an answer" flag was valid), but, at this point, I don't see a compelling reason to do so, given that, as someone pointed out in a comment and you yourself admit, the answer was not correct, and other correct answers have now been posted.

Again, to emphasize: moderators don't delete answers because they are incorrect or contain mistakes. That's not why this answer was originally deleted. It's only why I'm not *undeleting* it now, even though the original deletion may well have been in  error.

Comment: Actually, the answer does provide the solution and the same solution has been suggested by the other answer which you said are correct. The only reason for my statement "But, I still have no idea why it was happening.", was because I was unable to determine the reason why that specific line of code caused a problem.

But, I understand that I should've been more clear in my answer.

Comment: Where could we see the deleted answer. I think I reviewed this post too

Comment: @MichaelMao The answer in question is linked to in the question here, and a screenshot is even included for those who cannot see deleted posts. The answer went through the Low Quality Answers review queue, but [the actual review task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32583088) had no actions taken before it was deleted by a moderator. I see no evidence that you reviewed it, but it's certainly possible you Skipped it (I didn't spend enough time looking to go through your skips).

Comment: Maybe I skip it but I do see this post. Anyway. I just want to review what my reviewing is ok or not